# Settings View Mode in Android studio mac

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am facing very strange behaviour windows option in android studio hedgehog.
In toolbar -> Click on View Mode.. option and accidentally click on other options. Please check in the images.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

My ui looks like this

[image]

where is toolbar or any other options? How can I revert back this to normal view?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this behaviour - this happens from entering Distraction Free mode, then most likely opening the Project tool window either from View > Tool Windows > Project, or by invoking the key bind (Command+1). You should be able to exit Distraction Free mode by going to View > Appearance > Exit Distraction Free Mode, or from the steps as mentioned in Sandesh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps-

- Open Android Studio
- Press Windows or Command+Shift+A
- Search for View Mode
- Click on first options
- Exit the current mode which is active with android studio.

[image]